# Finding and removing duplicate files of a specific file extension or type in OS X with a script?

Tags: macos, terminal, script, duplicate

Not sure why but there doesn't seem to be a utility app that allows defining a search and delete duplicates by file extension or type.

Is it possible to do through some terminal script? Like for:

```
   Strata Design 3D CX Model
   .sd3
```

Comment: Choose your duplicate (no pun intended) question: https://superuser.com/q/481456, https://superuser.com/q/533601, https://superuser.com/q/487810, https://superuser.com/q/259148/, https://superuser.com/q/122451/ — `fdupes` may be what you are looking for. Next time, please do a little more research before asking.

Answer (score -1):

We have "DuplicateFilesDeleter" is our system optimization and a simple, but effective tool to locate 'Duplicate Files' in one or more selected search paths - allowing Windows to run faster and freeing up valuable hard disk space.

It scans the files and compares them based on Byte for Byte Comparison, which ensures 100% accuracy. You can then choose to delete the selected duplicate or original files. The program is multi-threaded and performs scans quickly.

-Joshua Rover

Comment: Except that this question is about macOS and this post looks like spam.